# Check to see if a user is running old code?

Tags: .net, deployment

We have an internal application we developed for our users. We house all the code on a unc share. We have a loader application that they initially run to download all the appropriate files to their PCs and then they run everything locally. For a variety of reasons we been having problems with users running old code. In some cases all of their files were old and in other cases it might have just been one file. Is there any good way to check all the associated files for the program to see if they are running an old version of any file? We want to be able to notify the user that they need to redeploy to pick up the latest changes.

Comment: Why are you not using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce)? That's what it is for.

Comment: @Ramhound Why do i need to post my code? In most cases the files are old because the user just needs to restart the application. It has nothing to do with how our code works. In the application i just need to detect they are running old code and notify them they need to close and reopen to get the latest changes

Comment: @Oded because this is a brownfield app that was originally written in .net framework 1.0 and with our workload management would never authorize us to take the time to rework how its deployed. Especially considering the number of custom things we do in our loader and trying to retrofit that into clickonce.

Comment: I swear people are sometimes downgrade happy. Why is this such a BAD question?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using something like [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to deploy the application.

Effectively this puts a wrapper around the application which is configured to call back to a server to see if a newer version of the application exists. If it does, then that is downloaded and replaces the existing version of the application on the client machine.

The good thing about systems like this is you don't have to do anything to your application. You just deploy it though ClickOnce and that does all the work for you.

Other systems are available from other suppliers that work on the same principles.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris unfortunately changing how our application is deployed is not an option. It would be to big of a rewrite at this point. What other techniques are you speaking of.

Comment: @user127954 - ClickOnce isn't a rewrite. You just select it as an deployment option. By other techniques I meant other deployment systems - sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes i'm sure for most application it isn't but rest assured for our app it would be. This isn't as simple as deploying all code to one directory then running. That would be to simple :P. We use this "deployment app" we use for servers (application & web), all applications we use. Our application is then strewn in a variety of custom places throughout the system and we have applications which spawn other applications. In 99.9% of the applications what you said would be true but not ours. Is it good? No. But it is what it is and we aren't allowed to change it because of the time involved.

Comment: Put it this way there is quite a bit of logic just in the way we load everything.